# How to get number of doubling propreties in object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

im trying to make o loop in an object json so that it can show me all the doubling of the propreties.

**This is my JSON file (departements-list.json)**:

```
 [
        {"Departement": "meryem"},
        {"Departement": "meryem"},
        {"Departement": "meryem"},
        {"Departement": "meryem"},
        {"Departement": "meryem"},
    
        {"Departement": "sara"},
        {"Departement": "sara"},
        {"Departement": "sara"},
    
        {"Departement": "ouss"},
        {"Departement": "ouss"},
        {"Departement": "ouss"},
    
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"},
        {"Departement": "samati"}
   ]
```

**And this is my js :**

```
  import departement_list from "../data/departements-list.json";
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(departement_list));
    
    for (var dep of jsonData) {
     let nb_dep = Object.keys(dep.Departement).length;
    
      console.log(dep.Departement, " =" , nb_dep);
    }
```

I had this result in the browser console :

```
meryem  = 6
3custom-map.js:20 sara  = 4
3custom-map.js:20 ouss  = 4
9custom-map.js:20 samati  = 6
```

Which is not logical !

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Comment: You're counting the characters in each deparments name instead of how many times it appears. I'm assuming your results should be: meryem=5, sara=3, ouss=3, samati=9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of how to get the number of occurrences for each department value. I first map the data to be a list of the department values. Then I create a new set to create an array of each value. Then I loop through each unique value, and filter the data by that value, and log the length or number of occurrences for each value.

```js
const jsonData = [
  {"Departement": "meryem"},
  {"Departement": "meryem"},
  {"Departement": "meryem"},
  {"Departement": "meryem"},
  {"Departement": "meryem"},

  {"Departement": "sara"},
  {"Departement": "sara"},
  {"Departement": "sara"},

  {"Departement": "ouss"},
  {"Departement": "ouss"},
  {"Departement": "ouss"},

  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"},
  {"Departement": "samati"}
];

const dataValues = jsonData.map(data => data.Departement);
const uniqueValues = [...new Set(dataValues)];
for (const val of uniqueValues) {
  console.log(`
    Val ${val}
    has ${dataValues.filter(v => v == val).length} entries
  `);
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's exactly what im lookin for.
can you tell me what this line do please : `const uniqueValues = [...new Set(dataValues)];`

Comment: I initialize a constant variable named `uniqueValues` on the left hand side, the value to be assigned is on the right. I am assigning an array, and the contents of the array are the values returned by the new set. I am using the [spread syntax operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass the items from a `new Set` into the array. A [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is an object like a list, with only unique entries.

Comment: Also, the spread syntax is not necessary here, just force of habit. Often when I use sets, I want array methods available to use the data. However, a `for`... `of` loop works just fine with a set, so I didn't need it.